# Can I leave my base to look for spadonium?

Tags: no-mans-sky

So I built the construction terminal and if I understood correctly, the next step is to build a science terminal, for which I require *Spadonium*. It doesn't exist on any planet in my base's system, and I can't build a beacon since I need the Science Terminal to get the required *Voltaic cell*.

So my question is, having not placed a beacon, may I leave the system to find a **Barren Biome** and then return to this system? Or is there a risk of losing my system? Is the system where I built my base remembered for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly. You can use the teleporter inside of the space stations in each star system to teleport back to your base. Your ship will also teleport.

The teleporters can be found in the right door of the space station  (after your ship lands and rotates).

Note thay previously you needed an Atlas Pass V1 to enter this door. This is no longer needed, as the doors are no longer locked.

Comment: This indeed seems to be the case, thanks for explaining a game mechanic that wasn't given!